# how to incorporate an array in an CLI command in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am having an hard time, implementing an array in an AWS cli command in ruby. 
I have a set of accounts, I want to get the policy version details of a specific policy from an specific account number. I want to loop through the account numbers and get the specific policy details for the account numbers.

HERE IS MY CURRENT CODE, it works when I hard code the account number

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

puts "Here is the current version of the CloudHealth Policy"

accnt  = [899163431116, 2382308203823, 8989089089080]
puts "here is the zero index" 
puts accnt [0]
j = `aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::899163431116:policy/cloudhealth-access-policy --version-id v2 --profile jo`
my_hash = JSON.parse(j)
puts JSON.pretty_generate my_hash["PolicyVersion"]
```

I WANT TO INCORPORATE THE ARRAY accnt, SO I CAN LOOP Through the accnt numbers with an hard coding in the cli command

```
 require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

puts "Here is the current version of the CloudHealth Policy"

accnt = [899163431116, 2382308203823, 8989089089080]
puts "here is the zero index" 
puts accnt[0]
j = `aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::accnt[0]:policy/cloudhealth-access-policy --version-id v2 --profile jo`
my_hash = JSON.parse(j)
puts JSON.pretty_generate my_hash["PolicyVersion"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interpolate you'll need to request interpolation:

```
j = `aws ... arn:aws:iam::#{accnt[0]}:policy...`
```

Strings are only interpolated if you use the `#{...}` notation to indicate you want that part to be expanded. In your acase `accnt[0]` is just plain text that's part of the string.

You'll probably want to expand your code to be more like this:

```
accnt.each do |id|
  j = `aws ... arn:aws:iam::#{id}:policy...`
  # ...Other code relating to parsing/printing for this round
end
```

Don't forget that the AWS Ruby library can do everything the command-line `aws` tool can do and more, so engaging the shell here is probably not necessary. The [Aws::IAM::Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/IAM/Policy.html) class should be able to get what you need.